# jquery unbinding and binding

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I just want to disable the ability for a user to click on an element for some condition and then re-bind it later for another condition. Here is some of the code I am working with:

```
 $('#navigation a').bind('click',function(e){

    var $this   = $(this);
    var prev    = current;

    current = $this.parent().index() + 1;

    if (current == 1){
       $("#navigation a:eq(1)").unbind("click"); // remove the click for element
    }
    if (current >= 2){
       $("#navigation a:eq(1)").bind("click"); // this doesn't work, but i want re-bind the click here.
    } }
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: How about returning false in function instead of binding/unbinding? Also, a named function would make things easier.

Comment: check out http://api.jquery.com/live/, I think you can do preventDefault() instead of unbind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you actually want to just disable the first navigation link from working. If that's the case, you simply want:

```
$("#navigation a:first").click(function () { return false; });
```

as returning `false` from an event handler prevents the browser's default action (of following the link) from occuring.

Although, if the link is not meant to be clickable, don't make it a link, turn it into a `<span>`:

```
var link = $("#navigation a:first");
$("<span>").text(link.text()).attr("class", link.attr("class"))
    .insertBefore(link);
link.remove();
```

(assuming that the class attribute of the link is the only worthy attribute to copy).

---

If you actually do wish to unbind the custom handler you wrote, then you want to give the handler function a *name* so it can be referenced again for rebinding:

```
$('#navigation a').bind('click', onClick);

function onClick(e) {
    var $this   = $(this);
    var prev    = current;

    current = $this.parent().index() + 1;

    if (current == 1){
       $("#navigation a:eq(1)").unbind("click"); // remove the click for element
    } else {
       $("#navigation a:eq(1)").bind("click", onClick); // use the function again
    }
}
```